# Initialize a variable with placeholder as shape

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I want to initialize the Weights variable by including the BatchSize dimension, which will be different between the Training and Prediction stages. Tried using the placeholder for that, but doesn't seem to work:

```
    batchsize = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, name='batchsize', shape=[])
    ...
    output, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(multicell, X, dtype=tf.float32, initial_state=inState)
    weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([batchsize, CELL_SIZE, 1], 0.0, 1.0), name='weights')
    bias = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(1), name='bias')
    preds = tf.add(tf.matmul(output, weights), bias, name='preds')
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(preds, Y_))
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(LR).minimize(loss)
```

I can get it to work by specifying `batchsize` as a constant for the `weights` variable dimension, as opposed to a placeholder, but this way I get an error when I try to recover the session for the Prediction stage, because there the `batchsize` is 1. If I specify the placeholder, I get the error:

```
ValueError: initial_value must have a shape specified: Tensor("truncated_normal:0", shape=(?, 32, 1), dtype=float32)
```

Even though I do pass the value for the `batchsize` placeholder into the `feed_dict` when running this part of the graph.

If I specify the option `validate_shape=False` while creating the weights variable, that stage of the graph works, but later I get this error in `AdamOptimizer`:

```
ValueError: as_list() is not defined on an unknown TensorShape.
```

How can I get this to work? My ultimate goal is to reduce the Cell-Size dimension of the `dynamic_rnn` output down to 1 to predict the output at each time-step of the RNN.

Comment: You don't really need to keep batch size in a placeholder. If you declare the first dimension of your variables as `None`, it will be calculated dynamically.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Trying that but getting this error: TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got None

Comment: Any solutions yet?

Comment: I moved on and instead just use the workaround -- when recovering the model for predictions, I just take the specific dimension from the overall matrix. It works OK for that specific task, but obviously not a good generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make the whole size of variable
2. get the specific shape of variable corresponding to the batch size (using tf.gather)

   self.model_X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 100], name='X')

   real_batch_size = tf.cast(tf.shape(self.model_X)[0],tf.int32)

   self.y_dk = tf.get_variable(name="y_dk",initializer=tf.truncated_normal(shape=[self.num_doc, self.num_topic],                                                                 mean=0, stddev=tf.truediv(1.0,self.lambda_y)), dtype=tf.float32)

   batch_y_dk = tf.reshape(tf.gather(self.y_dk, self.model_batch_data_idx), [real_batch_size, self.num_topic])